# How to re-render UI template base on condition vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

```
How to re-render UI template base on condition vuejs

<template>
  <text-box v-model="value" :rules="setValidate" />
</template

<script>
 export default {
  data() {
   return {
    setValidate : [],
   }
  },
  watch: {
    value(newValue){
        if(newValue === 'Modern') {
            this.setValidate = [(item) => !!item || 'This is required']
        } else {
            this.setValidate = [item => item]
        }
    }
  }  
}
</script>
```

I wanted to set the require rules base on watcher if input is Modern it will be required field otherwise it will be non require field. I am guessing it is not re-rendering template rule base on watcher, how can we fix it please guide

Thank you